# Prompt user to re-enter number

Tags: c, do-while

I'm doing a practice 'do while' program where I want the user to enter three numbers and the program will print the sum on screen. After receiving the answer, the program will ask the user if he wants to enter another three numbers to get another answer, and so on. I'm fine with this.

If user enters anything other than an integer ("A,!,%") etc, I want the program to prompt the user to re-enter a number. See comments in program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
Do - While

This program shall ask the user to enter
three numbers and print out the sum. Entering letters
or special characters will ask the user to re-enter that
number.

example:

Enter Number 1: 2
Enter Number 2: 5
Enter Number 3: 9

Answer is 16

...

Enter Number 1: 2
Enter Number 2: yum   here user incorrectly enters letters
Enter Number 2: 8     re-prompted to enter number to continue
Enter Number 3: 9

Answer is 19

*/

int main(void) {
    int a,b,c,ans,n;
    do{
        do{
            printf("Enter Number 1: ");
            scanf("%d", &a);
            printf("\n");
        }
        while((a>0) || (a<0)|| (a==0));

        do{
            printf("Enter Number 2: ");
            scanf("%d", &b);
            printf("\n");
        }
        while((b>0) || (b<0)|| (b==0));

        do{
            printf("Enter Number 3: ");
            scanf("%d", &c);
            printf("\n");
          }
        while ((c>0) || (c<0)|| (c==0));

        ans = a+b+c;

        printf("Answer is %d\n\n", ans);

        printf("Press 1 to start over, or 0 to quit...");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        printf("\n");

    }while (n!=0);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to use `scanf` for user input. You have already lost because there is no way to get `scanf` to behave sanely. You need to use something like `fgets` to read a line at once.

Comment: `while((a>0) || (a<0)|| (a==0))` is semantically equivalent to `while(1)`, so you have a plenty of dead / unreachable code. Is this what you wanted ?

Comment: @xing And if the user just hits enter, there's nothing you can do because `scanf` won't give you control back.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Not really lol. But that's something I was questioning myself. How can I have the program reprompt after incorrect entry? My thinking was to exclude all characters other than integers with that while statement.

Comment: @kam11011 Seems that you never run [your code](https://onlinegdb.com/r1hzXisIE) yourself

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Mr. Sarcastic.. I guess I don't run my own code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program contains multiple repeated sections. Since you are gathering three numbers, you should use a for loop which runs three times.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  /* ... */
}
```

Inside the for loop, you're gathering the `i+1`-th number each time. If the user doesn't enter a valid number, you keep trying to gather it. So the do-while loop containing the `printf` and `scanf` will go inside the for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  do {
    printf("Enter Number %d: ", i+1);
    scanf( /* ... */ );
  } while ( /* ... */ );
}
```

`scanf` returns the number of input items successfully read as an `int`. So the do-while loop should repeat as long as the return value of `scanf` is zero. We could store the return value in a variable and check the variable in the `while (...);`, but we can just move the `scanf` itself into the `while (...);`. We also need an array to store the three input numbers.

```
int n[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  do {
    printf("Enter Number %d: ", i+1);
  } while (scanf("%d", n+i) == 0);
}
```

The rest of the program would loop over the array and store the sum of the elements. You would then output the sum. This approach is robust and maintainable as changing the amount of input numbers is easy and repeated or similar code sections are eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fgets to get the input and use strtol() to cast the string the user input into an int. If strtol returns 0 when the user input does not start with a number or have a number in it. From there you can check if the user input is 0 and then reprompt the user until a is not 0.

```
*instead of scanf()*
char num1[5];
char *end;
fgets(num1, 5, stdin);
a = strtol(num1, &end, 10);
while( a = 0){
    fgets....
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you contribution. I hear alot to use fgets but unfortunately right now I'm just trying to grasp the idea of scanf since I am in a  C programming class and fgets is outside the scope of the class. Is there a way to use if else, or do while statements to achieve this?

Comment: If you MUST use scanf() then here is how one way that works:

Comment: char nb[3];
        int nums[3];
        char *end;
        for (int i = 0; i<3; i++){
                printf("Enter number %d: ", i+1);
                scanf("%s", nb);
                fflush(stdin);
                nums[i] = strtol(nb, &end, 10);
                while( nums[i] == 0 ){
                        printf("Invalid Number! Enter number: ");
                        scanf("%s", nb);
                        nums[i] = strtol(nb, &end, 10);
                }
        }
        ans = nums[0]+ nums[1]+ nums[2];